# How do I set DocumentRoot/Directory path in XAMPP httpd.conf to USB flash folder?

Tags: usb, permissions, xampp

*I use Lubuntu 13.10 with XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3 and my USB flash is FAt32 formated.*

When I try to set XAMPP configuration file /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:

```xml
<Directory />
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
</Directory>

    DocumentRoot "/media/username/USB_FLASH/www"

<Directory "/media/username/USB_FLASH/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I get:

> **Access forbidden!**
>   You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>   **Error 403**

Comment: Is your usb formatted in NTFS/FAT? You should use ext4 instead.

Comment: I can't format usb flash disk to ext4 because I use it on Linux and Windows... anyway after whole day I found solution

Comment: Which was the solution? FAT doesn't support Linux permissions

Comment: Please move your answer from your question into an answer below. That way, you can accept it and the question will be automatically shown as 'solved'

Comment: I can do that after 8 hours - not now... I'm new here

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after 5 hours of searching...

```
    <IfModule unixd_module>
        User username
        Group username
    </IfModule> 
# username means your linux login username!

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

        DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/www"

    <Directory "/opt/lampp/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory> 
# DocumentRoot path and Directory path are symbolic link to /media/username/USB_FLASH/www folder!
```

Then, I made a symbolic link with Terminal emulator:

```
sudo ln -s /media/username/USB_FLASH/www /opt/lampp
```

and then a symbolic link is made from /media/username/USB_FLASH/www to /opt/lampp.

Comment: This link file is not visible via www for me. But that (change user name in config) work for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250937/accessing-an-external-hard-drive-sites-from-xampp-in-kubuntu-20-04