# Accessing an external hard drive sites from xampp in kubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, permissions, kubuntu, apache2, xampp

I have an external usb hard drive "ExtHD1TB" with an NTFS file system.

I installed XAMPP in my PC with kubuntu 20.04 (ext4 file system)

I want to access my sites from xampp directly from the external hard drive because in my work I have to use a windows pc, which also has XAMPP installed and I can access my external hard drive sites to work with.

My sites are located in `/media/user/ExtHD1TB/DATOS/SITES/MyWEBS/examplesite` according to my kubuntu.

To acomplish that I create a virtual host in my httpd-vhost.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/media/user/ExtHD1TB/DATOS/SITES/MyWEBS/examplesite"
    ServerName examplesite.localhost
    ServerAlias www.examplesite.localhost
    <Directory "/media/user/ExtHD1TB/DATOS/SITES/MyWEBS/examplesite">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/examplesite.localhost-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/examplesite.localhost-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and uncoment the line `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in my `httpd.conf` file

Since that did not make the work done I tried to add an alias to my `httpd.conf` file so I added this:

```
DocumentRoot "/media/user/ExtHD1TB/DATOS/SITES/MyWEBS/examplesite"
<Directory "/media/user/ExtHD1TB/DATOS/SITES/MyWEBS/examplesite">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and this

```
Alias /examplesite "/media/user/ExtHD1TB/DATOS/SITES/MyWEBS/examplesite"
```

to the `<IfModule alias_module>` of my `httpd.conf` file

but it didn't work either. I allways get this message when I try to access the site `localhost/examplesite` or `examplesite.localhost`

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is
> either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
> Error 403 examplesite.localhost Apache/2.4.43 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.6
> mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

I am starting to think that the problem is xampp accessing the ntfs file system.

If you could please help me It will be very apreciated.

Thank you very much for your time.

WaGo

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out that you can change the User and Group in `httpd.conf`to match your username and group.

My username was `ben`and the group was also `ben` so I changed it from `daemon` to `ben`in `http.conf`

Previous httpd.conf

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>
```

New httpd.conf

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User ben
Group ben
</IfModule>
```

Now my virtual hosts work.

My virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/media/ben/Larder/Projects/payroll/public"
    ServerName payroll.devo
  <Directory "/media/ben/Larder/Projects/payroll/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Document root setting in `httpd.conf`

```
DocumentRoot "/media/ben/Larder/Projects"
<Directory "/media/ben/Larder/Projects">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```